# How to see keybindings in `package-list-package`

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

How to see keybindings in `package-list-package` in Emacs?
I know only open a package by Enter, and Enter `Install` text to install it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> is bound to `(describe-mode)`. The key-binding is ubiquitous across all `major-mode` like the one [abo-abo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19449306/1309352) pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as for any major mode: <kbd>f1 m</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm setting `f1` to another function so I use `describe-mode` function.